# Solve $x+3y=4y^3,y+3z=4z^3 ,z+3x=4x^3$ in reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Find answers of this system of equations in reals$$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> x+3y=4y^3 \\ 
> y+3z=4z^3  \\
> z+3x=4x^3  
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

*Things O have done:* summing these 3 equations give $$4(x+y+z)=4(x^3+y^3+z^3)$$
$$x+y+z=x^3+y^3+z^3$$

I've also tried to show that $x,y,z$ should be between $1$ and $-1$(As $(-1,-1,-1)$ and  $(1,1,1)$ are answers of this system of equations) but I was not successful.

Comment: It reminds me of $$\cos3A$$ formula

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No.i self studying algebra and this was a question from book that i was not able to solve it.

Comment: You can see that $(0,0,0),(1,1,1), (-1,-1,-1)$ are solutions.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal,thanks.but is there any better way beside guessing? I wish i knew about functions so i could understand the answer is posted here.

Comment: @user2838619: There are advanced techniques but you need to know some algebraic geometry.

Comment: The equations are cyclic. We can replace x (or y or z) with y or z or x. So, the three values have to be equal. If you take that, x=0, x=1 and x=-1 are clearly solutions.

Comment: @tpb261 $x=-y, y=-x$ is also a cyclic system of equations, but by no means does it imply $x=y$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that we had $x>1$.  Then, since $4x^3-3x > x$, we have $z>x$, and similarly $y>z$, $x>y$, contradiction.  By symmetry, we conclude that $x,y,z\in [-1,1]$.

So there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in [0,\pi]$ with $x=\cos \alpha$, $y=\cos \beta$, $z=\cos \gamma$.  By the formula for $\cos 3\alpha$, we can rewrite the system of equations as:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \equiv \pm 3 \beta\ (\operatorname{mod}\ 2\pi) \\ 
\beta = \pm 3 \gamma\ (\operatorname{mod}\ 2\pi)  \\
\gamma = \pm 3\alpha\ (\operatorname{mod}\ 2\pi)  
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So we have $\pm 27\alpha \equiv \alpha$, so either $26\alpha \equiv 0$ or $28\alpha \equiv 0$.  We find that $\alpha = \pi k / 13$ or $\alpha = \pi k / 14$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.

This gives $27$ solutions,* $x=\cos{\frac{\pi k}{13}}$ for $0\leq k\leq 13$, and $x=\cos{\frac{\pi k}{14}}$ for $1\leq k\leq 13$.

For example, one solution is $(\cos\frac{\pi}{14},\cos\frac{9\pi}{14},\cos\frac{3\pi}{14})$.

* This is exactly the number we expect, up to multiplicity, when intersecting three cubic surfaces; in particular there are no more solutions over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Well thought and well written; the techniques used are well within the precalculus realm.

Comment: I think this solution is incorrect because if X lies between -1 and 0 also we'll get z>x, y>z and x>y. Similarly if X is not 1, 0 and -1 we get other way round. Which means x should be either 0 or 1 or -1. And these are the only real solutions.

Comment: @saisaandeep I think you're mistaken. I found a small error—I mixed up y and z in the example solution—but you can verify computationally that $(x,y,z) = (\cos\frac{\pi}{14},\cos\frac{9\pi}{14},\cos\frac{3\pi}{14})$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = 4x^3 - 3x$. We have: $f'(x) = 12x^2 - 3 = 0 \iff x = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus:

If $x \in \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ then $f'(x) < 0$, and $f$ decreases. This means:

If $x > y > z$, then: $x = f(y) < f(z) = y$, a contradiction. And we can obtain a contradiction for any other inequalities of $x,y,z$ using the same argument. The same argument works for $x \leq -\dfrac{1}{2}$ or $x \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$ since then $f$ increases.

For if $x > y = z$, then: $y = f(z) > f(x) = z$, contradiction again. Thus we must have:

$x = y = z$, and we have: $x = y = z = \pm 1$ and $0$

Comment: How about $x=y=z=0$?

Comment: The tags on the question, and op's comment, indicate that this is to be done with precalculus techniques. So the derivative can't be used.

Comment: This assumes that all of $x,y,z$ lie in the same region.  But there are solutions where they don't.