# Distinct real solution of $27$ degree equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Total number of distinct real solutions  of the equation
>
> $x^3-3x=y\;\;,y^3-3y=z\;\;,z^3-3z=x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Put $y=x^3-3x$ in $z=y^3-3y$

We get $z=(x^3-3x)^3-3(x^3-3x)$ put into $z^3-3z=x$

So we get $$\left[(x^3-3x)^3-3(x^3-3x)\right]^3-3\left[(x^3-3x)^3-3(x^3-3x)\right] = x$$

Now how can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Comment: So the problem asks only *how many* solutions there are.

Comment: Yes ajotatxe  i mean same thing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the number of integer solutions they are looking for ? From what I can see, $x=y=z$ is probably a solution which happens three times.

Comment: Up to some scaling and relabelling of $x,y,z$, this is equivalent to a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891954/59379) asked two months ago.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all equal, you have $x^3-3x=x$, which has solutions $\{-2,0,2\}$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3x%3Dy,y%5E3-3y%3Dz,z%5E3-3z%3Dx) finds a bunch more numerically that have such small imaginary parts they are probably real.  Click on the more solutions button to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^3-3x$. 
If $|x| > 2$ then $|f(x)| > |x|$, and iterating $f$ on some $x$ with $|x|>2$ produces a sequence that diverges to infinity, and so you can't have a cycle in there.

So it is enough to study the dynamics of $f$ in the segment $[-2;2]$.

You can check that $f(-2) = f(1) = -2$ and $f(-1)=f(2)=2$. In fact the restrictions of $f$ to $A = [-2;-1], B = [-1;1]$ and $C = [1;2]$ are all bijections onto $[-2;2]$.

From there, there is almost a bijection between points $x \in [-2;2]$ and infinite sequence of letters in $\{A;B;C\}$ describing in which interval $f^{\circ n}(x)$ fall into.

Given an finite sequence $(L_n)$ of letters the set of points whose sequence begins with $(L_n)$ is the closed interval $(f|_{L_1}^{-1} \circ f|_{L_2}^{-1} \circ \ldots \circ f|_{L_n}^{-1})([-2 ; 2])$.

If you look at the $27$ sequences of length $3$ you get that $[-2;2]$ is divided into $27$ subintervals where $f^{\circ 3}$ is onto $[-2;2]$, and each one contains at least a fixpoint (aka a $3$-cycle). Since you can have only at most $27$ points in $3$-cycles, there are exactly $27$ of them.

Given an infinite sequence of letters, you obtain a decreasing sequence of closed segments that converge to a point (actually this point is hard to prove, and not necessary, but it provides some intuition).

The map point -> sequence isn't bijective because $-1$ and $1$ can be considered belonging to two intervals. so $-1$ correspond to both sequences $ACCCC\ldots$ and $BCCCC\ldots$. Though if you think about it, it's a lot like our usual decimal system.

---

Or, you know some trigonometry and that $2\cos(3t) = (2\cos(t))^3-3(2\cos(t))$
so if you start on $x = 2\cos(t)$ for some $t \in \Bbb R$, then its images are the $2\cos(3^nt)$

Then the $3$-periodic points are the $2\cos(2k\pi/
26)$ and $2\cos(2l\pi/28)$ for $k=0 \ldots 13$ and $l=1 \ldots 13$